# How do I run some command every time the new terminal window is open in VS Code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

So I want to run `source ~/.bashrc` in VSCode terminal so I can load my own command to run on it. Right now I have to manually on the command line. Are there anyway I can run the command before the terminal start? (OS: Mac)

Comment: Which OS is this? Windows, Linux or macOS? Depending on that, you might have to put your commands in `~/.bash_profile` instead...

Comment: @nwinkler maybe my question is not clear but I want to run the file at the start of the terminal. Something like `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I have the same question. For my use case, I want to load certain envrionment variables to the terminal, but I do not want those variables set globally for terminal environments outside of VS Code (e.g. loading my AWS creds to env variables and setting a DEV_MODE=1 env variable that is used by certain scripts.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using macOS, the `~/.bashrc` file is not used, instead it's `~/.bash_profile`. You can do one of the following:

- Put your custom commands in `~/.bash_profile`, or
- Source your `~/.bashrc` from your `~/.bash_profile`:

  - Create a file `~/.bash_profile` with the following content:

    ```
    source ~/.bashrc
    ```
  - Give the new file the same permissions as  `~/.bashrc`